# Help me compile this code

Tags: algorithm2e, pseudocode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{CAS}\label{CAS}
 {$\sum^{N_{C}}_{i=1}$$L_C$} $\gets$ position of \textit{$canditate_i$}\\
{$\sum^{N_{C}}_{i=1}$$D_{C_i}$} $\gets$ distance of \textit{(eNB,$canditate_i$)}\\
\textit{$i$}=$N_C$\\
sort $D_{C_i}$ by descending order\\
$i=N_C$
\While{\textit{$i$}> 0}{
\textit{$i$}= \textit{$i$} - 1

\textit{select $canditiate_i$ as agent}

\textit{random($$D_{C_i}$}select $canditate_i$ as agent}
}


\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I encounter a compile problem.

I think I'm not Not familiar with its  algorithm2e's grammar.

please help me fix this code!!

Comment: irrelevant to the question, but i think the word "canditate" (also "canditiate") is really meant to be "candidate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing math mode: there's no need to exit and reenter it; also `\textit{$i$}` is useless. Conversely, multicharacter variable names should be typeset with `\mathit` in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{CAS}\label{CAS}
$\sum^{N_{C}}_{i=1}L_C \gets \text{position of } \mathit{candidate}_i$\\
$\sum^{N_{C}}_{i=1}D_{C_i} \gets\text{distance of } (\mathit{eNB},\mathit{candidate}_i)$\\
$i=N_C$\\
sort $D_{C_i}$ by descending order\\
$i=N_C$
\While{$i>0$}{
$i=i - 1$

select $\mathit{candidate}_i$ as agent

$\mathit{random}(D_{C_i})$ select $\mathit{candidate}_i$ as agent
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This solution finds errors and corrected in line 15, 20 and added rule and linenumbers into it, making it more readable.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{CAS}\label{CAS}
 {$\sum^{N_{C}}_{i=1}$$L_C$} $\gets$ position of \textit{$canditate_i$}\\
{$\sum^{N_{C}}_{i=1}$$D_{C_i}$} $\gets$ distance of \textit{(eNB,$canditate_i$)}\\
\textit{$i$}=$N_C$\\
sort $D_{C_i}$ by descending order\\
$i=N_C$

\While{\textit{i} $> 0$}{
\textit{$i$}= \textit{$i$} - 1

\textit{select $canditiate_i$ as agent}

\textit{random($D_{C_i}$) select $canditate_i$ as agent}
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you think that `\textit{$i$}= \textit{$i$} - 1` is correct?

Comment: Well, I would say $i=i-1$ is correct in terms of programming pseudo code. But I won't use \textit{$i$} writing. Please enlighten me, I am not totally understand your question.

Comment: I meant it's incorrect from the typesetter point of view: the `-` becomes a hyphen and the spacing is all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To be compiled this line

```
\textit{random($$D_{C_i}$}select $canditate_i$ as agent} }
```

is changed. there are some other changes, however I am not sure, if it is a final version.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document} 
\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{CAS}
\label{CAS} 
{$\sum^{N_{C}}_{i=1}$$L_C$} $\gets$ position of \textit{$canditate_i$}\\
 {$\sum^{N_{C}}_{i=1}$$D{C_i}$} $\gets$ distance of \textit{(eNB,$canditate_i$)}\\ 
\textit{$i$}=$N_C$\ sort $D_{C_i}$ by descending order\\
 $i=N_C$ \While{{$i> 0$}}{{$i$}= {$i - 1$}

\textit{select $canditiate_i$ as agent}

\textit{random($D_{C_i}$}select $canditate_i$ as agent} 

\end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Please observe that instead of constructions like `\textit{$i$} - 1` there should be simply `$i-1$`.

Comment: Of course `\textit{$i$}=$N_C$` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**try this ..**

```
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{CAS}\label{CAS}
 {$\sum^{N_{C}}_{i=1}$$L_C$} $\gets$ position of \textit{$canditate_i$}\\
{$\sum^{N_{C}}_{i=1}$$D_{C_i}$} $\gets$ distance of \textit{(eNB,$canditate_i$)}\\
\textit{$i$}=$N_C$\\
sort $D_{C_i}$ by descending order\\
$i=N_C$
\While{\textit{$i$}> 0}{
\textit{$i$}= \textit{$i$} - 1

\textit{select $canditiate_i$ as agent}

\textit{random($D_{C_i}$}select $canditate_i$ as agent}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```